# How to refresh particurlar element in javascript

Tags: javascript, refresh

I am trying to display the date and simultaneously refresh it to show each second

Where did I go wrong?

```
<script>
    function  abcd(){
        var date = new Date();
        document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Today is: " + date +  "</h1>";
    }

    setInterval(abcd(),1000);
</script>
```

Comment: replace `abcd()` with `abcd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows use abcd instead of abcd()

```js
         function  abcd(){
         var date = new Date();
         document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Today is: " + date +  "</h1>";
      }

       setInterval(abcd,1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you write setInterval(abcd(),1000), then the function abcd is invoked immediately and the return value of abcd is passed which is undefined in this case so actually you are writing setInterval(undefined, 1000) because of which your code doesn't work as expected. Just pass the name of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As @gurvinder372 mentioned, the interface of `setInterval` function is a function and an integer.
You need to pass the function itself and not the invocation of it.

```js
function abcd() {
  var date = new Date();
  document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Today is: " + date + "</h1>";
}

setInterval(abcd, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `abcd` and `abcd()` is that the first is a *reference* and the second will return a *value* (in your case `undefined`)

## Why pass in a Reference

The reference can be execute inside a function

#### Example

```js
function logMe() {
  console.log('Hi :o')
}

function logMeToo() {
  console.log('Bye')
}

function messageLogger(youFunction) {
  youFunction()
}

messageLogger(logMe)
messageLogger(logMeToo)
```

## Code

```js
function abcd() {
  var date = new Date();
  document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Today is: " + date + "</h1>";
}

setInterval(abcd, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code while calling the function:

```
setInterval(function(){
 abcd();
}, 1000);
```